# Segmentation of time series into one-second non-overlapping windows

Tags: python, time-series

I need to split the time series dataset (accelerometer values (timestamp, X, Y, Z)) into segments in the form of a one-second window that does not overlap. I am trying to find an example of its implementation, but found nothing. I'm a beginner and don't know how to do this.

Comment: Assuming you have many values per second, you could just group the points by second (from hh:mm:ss:000ms to hh:mm:ss:999ms) and for every group calculate the mean of every coordinate. Of course some information will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260929/how-to-use-a-context-window-to-segment-a-whole-log-mel-spectrogram-ensuring-the/54326750#54326750) has an implementation for audio spectrograms, but it is exactly the same for any multivariate time-series.

Here is the most relevant part of the code. To not have any overlap, set `window_hop = window_size`.

```
window_size = 64
window_hop = 30
start_frame = window_size 
end_frame = window_hop * math.floor(float(frames.shape[1]) / window_hop)

for frame_idx in range(start_frame, end_frame, window_hop):
    window = frames[:, frame_idx-window_size:frame_idx]
```